# Why my Tkinter freezes while grabing and showing price from web?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, freeze

I'm trying to make a program that grabs live prices from web and shows them to tkinter. I barely handled loop system for prices consistently but when it comes to performance, it is freezing in every grabbing price moment. It lasts 1 or 2 seconds but however this is not good.

Here are my codes. Where am i doing wrong?

```
from tkinter import*
import time
from tkcalendar import*
from datetime import date
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import feedparser
import json
import threading

pencere = Tk()
pencere.geometry("300x300") 


live_prices = LabelFrame(pencere, text="Live prices", height=256, width=256)
live_prices.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10, pady=0)


type_label = Label(live_prices, text="Type                       ", bg="grey", fg="white")
type_label.place(x=5, y=5)

price_label = Label(live_prices, text="Price   ", bg="grey", fg="white")
price_label.place(x=130, y=5)

def quartergold():
    url = requests.get("https://bigpara.hurriyet.com.tr/kobi/dunya-emtia-borsalari/sgldc-ceyrek-altin/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    linkler = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"value"})
    ceyrek = linkler[0].text
    ceyrek = ceyrek[0:5]
    ceyrek = float(ceyrek)*1000

    ceyrek_metin = Label(live_prices, text="1/4 gold price ")
    ceyrek_metin.place(x=5, y=30)

    ceyrek_fiyat = Label(live_prices, text=ceyrek, font='Helvetica 12 bold')
    ceyrek_fiyat.place(x=130, y=30)
    live_prices.after(7000, quartergold)

quartergold()


def halfgold():
    urlyarm = requests.get("https://bigpara.hurriyet.com.tr/altin/yarim-altin-fiyati/")
    soupyarm = BeautifulSoup(urlyarm.content, "html.parser")
    linkleryarm = soupyarm.find_all("span", {"class":"value"})
    yarim = linkleryarm[0].text
    yarim = yarim[0:5]
    yarim = float(yarim)*1000

    yarim_metin = Label(live_prices, text="1/2 gold price ")
    yarim_metin.place(x=5, y=50)

    yarim_fiyat = Label(live_prices, text=yarim, font='Helvetica 12 bold')
    yarim_fiyat.place(x=130, y=50)
    live_prices.after(7000, halfgold)

halfgold()


def wholegold():
    url_tum = requests.get("https://bigpara.hurriyet.com.tr/altin/cumhuriyet-altini-fiyati/")
    soupiki = BeautifulSoup(url_tum.content, "html.parser")
    linkleriki = soupiki.find_all("span", {"class":"value"})
    tum = linkleriki[0].text
    tum = tum[0:5]
    tum = float(tum)*1000

    tum_metin = Label(live_prices, text="Whole Gold price ")
    tum_metin.place(x=5, y=70)

    yarim_fiyat = Label(live_prices, text=tum, font='Helvetica 12 bold')
    yarim_fiyat.place(x=130, y=70)
    live_prices.after(7000, wholegold)

wholegold()


def gramgold():
    url_gram = requests.get("https://bigpara.hurriyet.com.tr/altin/gram-altin-fiyati/")
    soupgram = BeautifulSoup(url_gram.content, "html.parser")
    linklergram = soupgram.find_all("span", {"class":"value"})
    gramm = linklergram[0].text
    gramm = gramm[0:5]

    gram_metin = Label(live_prices, text="gram gold price ")
    gram_metin.place(x=5, y=90)

    gram_fiyat = Label(live_prices, text=gramm, font='Helvetica 12 bold')
    gram_fiyat.place(x=130, y=90)
    live_prices.after(7000, gramgold)

gramgold()
    




pencere.mainloop()
```

Comment: You imported threading but you are not using it. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I imported threading to make threading system but when i couldn't, i erased my threading codes. Only import part left unerased. So i didn't erase it that i knew i will use it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example on why you should use classes.
You need to use multiple threads to run the prices in the background then use a timer to update the GUI on the main thread.

```py
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.myvar1 = 0 ##basically a global value for this class
        self.myvar2 = 0
    def get_price_1(self):
        get('http...')
        ....
        self.myvar1 = price
    def get_price2(self):
        get('http...')
        ....
        self.myvar2 = price
    def update_prices(self): ##runs every 10 seconds in a background thread
        t1=Thread(target=self.get_price_1)
        t2=Thread(target=self.get_price_1)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        self.root.after(10000, self.update_prices) ## schedules to run 10 seconds later
    def update_gui(self):
        self.my_lable1.configure(text=self.myvar1)
        self.my_lable2.configure(text=self.myvar2)
        self.root.after(1000, self.update_gui) ##re-runs ever 1 second

    def run(self):
        self.my_lable1 = Label(self.root)
        self.my_lable2 = Label(self.root)
        self.update_prices()
        self.update_gui()
        self.root.mainloop()
```

This wont be perfect but hopefully it explains the general idea.

Notes:
You cannot update a Tkinter widget from a background thread which is why i have to use 2 timers, the first updates the gui in the main thread and the second spawns the threads to get the prices in background threads.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I tried to apply your answer to my codes exactly. However i meet some problems. There are some unclear points for me because of I’m newbie in python.

1- Tkinter doesn’t show the labels when I’m following your code. Can there be parts that you didn’t think necessary to share with me by thinking that i already know but in fact I don’t know?

2-How can I make my class visible in tkinter? If I know the answer of question 1, you may not need to answer.